# How can I pass on a url variable from 1 page to another?

Tags: php, forms, variables

I've currently got a referral script running on my website but i've ran into a problem and unfortunately I don't know enough php to solve it.

The script grabs a variable 'ref' from the url but I don't have that variable by the time they get to the page where the script is running.

so the process is

```
homepage.com/?ref=XXXXX
>user clicks on script page
homepage.com/script.php
```

I need it to be

```
homepage.com/?ref=XXXXX
>user clicks on script page
>homepage passes variable to script page
homepage.com/script.php?ref=XXXXX
```

I don't have any code running on my homepage. The code on the script page is

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['ref_link'])){
    $ref = $_COOKIE['ref_link'];
}else{
    $ref = rand(1,9).date('Y').date('m').date('d').date('h').date('i').date('s');
    $ref = rand_uniqid($ref);
    setcookie("ref_link",$ref, 9999999999);  

    $insert = "insert into cookie_ref(REF_val) values('".$ref."');";
    @mysql_query($insert);

}
$error = ''; //used for checking if ip has been re used
if(isset($_GET['ref'])){
    $getip = "select * from cookie_ref_ips where IP_address = '".getRealIpAddr()."' and REF_val = '".$_GET['ref']."'";
    $getip_query = @mysql_query($getip);
    if(@mysql_num_rows($getip_query) < 1){
    $update = "update cookie_ref set REF_hits = REF_hits + 1 where REF_val = '".$_GET['ref']."'";
    @mysql_query($update);

    $insertip = "insert into cookie_ref_ips(IP_address,REF_val) values('".getRealIpAddr()."','".$_GET['ref']."')";
    @mysql_query($insertip);
    }else{
        $error = "<h1>You already used this refferal link!</h1>";
    }
}
```

this is a bit more complicated than I thought it would be because the homepage is running off wordpress where as the script page is a standalone page that calls the wordpress header. So I can't start a session in the wordpress header file as it will start it again because the header file is called in the script. Any suggestions?

Comment: on your script.php page, what happens when you do this: var_dump($_GET['ref']); ?

Comment: Also, if you could code for homepage.php and script.php then that would be helpful.

Comment: in the href that creates the url you need to add script.php?GET['whatever']

Comment: Updated the post, maximus. Mihai, could you give me an example of how to use that?

Comment: @user2619611 show us the code in that page

Comment: so what is not working on script.php? the code looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

If u have html source put link

```
homepage.com/script.php?ref=<?php $_GET['ref']?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it in the script_page using:

```
$newvar = $_GET['ref'];
```

but you make sure that in the homepage.html you have something like:

```
<form method="get" action="script_page.php">   
     <input type="some_type" name="ref">   
</form>
```

By the way how did you get your variable? asking the user, a DB or how?

Answer (score 0):

Use session cookies.

On your 'homepage.php':

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['ref'] = $_GET['ref'];
    header("Location: script.php"); // You can remove this if you want to redirect the user some other way.
?>
```

On your 'script.php':

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $ref = $_SESSION['ref']; // Your variable from the first script.
?>
```

Comment: This makes it auto redirect.  what if he doesnt want to redir?

Comment: what is this part for header("Location: script.php") and what should i replace it with?

Comment: That is what you use to point to a new file and instantly load that file.  So instead of it loading the php page, it will point to whatever Location says, some new page.

Answer (score 0):

if they click client side:

```
function getParameterByName(name){
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)"), result = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results == null ? "":decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, "");
}
```

which will allow you to get the param contents and say:

```
<a tar="">click</a>
var name = "ref";
$("a").on("click", function(){ $(this).attr("tar", NEWURL+"?"+name+"="getParameterByName(name))});
```

Or when building the page server side:

```
name = "ref";
echo "<a tar='".URL."?".name."=".$_REQUEST[name];
```

ALSO: as posted by others, you can use $_SESSION to save variables across pages as long as you have session_start(); at the top of your php page.

$_REQUEST is used because while you are talking about $_GET specifically, you could manage the same thing if the first page received the vars via POST.   $_REQUEST is the combination of both $_GET and $_POST and $_COOKIE

Comment: this is a bit more complicated than I thought it would be because the homepage is running off wordpress where as the script page is a standalone page that calls the wordpress header. So I can't start a session in the wordpress header file as it will start it again because the header file is called in the script. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have not done Wordpress except for when a user wanted me to make them a custom widget.  There is a lot of garbage in there which is used by wordpress as a company.  I usually just run my own server instances.

Comment: If you can, i would add a header at the top of the page, which will go to a new location.  Then you will have a blank page to work with.